# Is Scribble in c++ a tutorial to learn MFC or is a library, api, or something else?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I was explained that scribble is a library related with MFC but in my internet search I found that is a tutorial [to illustrate a wide breadth of MFC features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa233487(vs.60).aspx), but I'm not completely sure.

Someone with experience in c++ and visual studio can help me to understand this?

Comment: It's just a sample program that demonstrates how you can use the MFC library, it's not a library itself

Comment: Unless you are really working in Visual Studio 6.0 (sorry if you are), you should look at [this link to the latest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35t8fts(v=vs.100).aspx). It lets you select alternate versions for older Visual Studio from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Further to the comments made. **Scribble** is an application that you learn to develop. It teaches you fundamentals of using the **MFC** library.

To get started with **Scribble** you can follow this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716527(v=vs.60).aspx).

Here is an additional link to the more recent [source code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35t8fts(v=vs.100).aspx).

To quote the tutorial:

> Scribble, the application you build in this tutorial, is a small drawing program that poses a realistic trial run in the Windows programming environment of the traditional “Hello, World!” Scribble lets the user draw “Hello, World!” (or any free-hand drawing) by using the mouse and then save the image in a file.

Comment: You have linked the Visual Studio 6 version. [Latest Version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35t8fts(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @crashmstr Great, I couldn't find it. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @crashmstr: You have linked to the sample code. The link in this answer links to the tutorial, and this *is* the most recent version of the tutorial. The tutorial is way more helpful than just the sample code.